# Why "OpenCV's CV_Error" isn't catchable in Android owned C++ sources?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm using OpenCV(4.2.0) in an android project. When calling some opencv methods from android project's C++ files, opencv throws `CV_Error` and the application terminates/crashes. Instead of the crash I want to handle the exception and resume the program. Is there anyway to catch those exceptions in the projects' C++ file? I have tried the following and it doesn't work.

```
try {
......

} catch (...) {

}
```

**Here is the stack trace from crashlytics**

[image: Here is the stack trace from crashlytics]

For some reason the **CV_error** `#define CV_Error( code, msg ) cv::error( code, msg, CV_Func, __FILE__, __LINE__ )` isn't catchable in android project owned C++ files. I have even tried the following just to check out. The catch block isn't executed.

```
try {
    CV_Error(Error::StsBadArg, "Quadrangle is nonconvex or degenerated.");
} catch (...) {
    // not catched
}
```

Comment: In debug build [CV_error](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga5b48c333c777666e076bd7052799f891) crashes the app.  In release build, it throws an exception.  Are you in debug build?

Comment: Thanks @Eljay for the comment. It's not related to debug/release build. Somehow it has something to do with ndkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the answer if someone else also bumps into the same issue.

The issue is somehow related to `ndkVersion` used in the project. After upgrading the `ndkVersion` to `22.1.7171670`, `CV_Error` exceptions were catched successfully in the android project.

So the solution is to add the following line in `build.gradle` file of the app.

`ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'`

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      .......
      ndkVersion '22.1.7171670'
    }
}
```